# JQuery source code questions

Tags: jquery

I got two questions about following code snippet.

(1). What is the purpose of "return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );"? Why does it return another instance inside the JQuery function?

(2). Why prototype.constructor is re-defined as JQuery?

```
// Define a local copy of jQuery
var jQuery = function( selector, context ) {
        // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
        return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
    },

... ...

jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = {
    constructor: jQuery,
    init: function( selector, context, rootjQuery ) {
        var match, elem, ret, doc;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. When JQuery is called as an ordinary function, a new (class) instance of JQuery is created and returned using `new JQuery.fn.init(...)`. In this way, developers don't have to add the `new` keyword before `$(..)`.
2. `JQuery.fn` is a shortcut for `JQuery.prototype`. Writing `JQuery.fn.customMethod = function(){...}` is more convenient than writing `JQuery.prototype.customMethod = ...`. Because JQuery is often also accessible through `$` or `$j`, The shortesy way to refer to `JQuery.prototype` is `$.fn`.

Comment: Hi Rob, what is "rootjQuery" parameter for? Thanks.

Comment: `rootQuery` is an internal parameter to refer to the JQuery-wrapped root of the document.

Answer (score 1):

> (2). Why prototype.constructor is re-defined as JQuery?

I think the reason is to keep a constructor reference inside each jQuery object, to actually itself (it creates a circular reference). In fact, by overriding the `jQuery.prototype` object with this piece of code

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = { ... }
```

you lose the "automatically created" constructor (which points to the function it has been created from, in this case `jQuery.fn.init`), so you need to explicitly set it.

I've found this link very helpful to understand javascript prototype and contructor:

http://joost.zeekat.nl/constructors-considered-mildly-confusing.html